What is considered a late check-in in a bag tag?
I see this bag tag in this answer by lambshaanxy:



What is considered a late check-in in a bag tag? Does that mean a check-in after the check-in deadline? Of if it means a check-in before the check-in deadline, what's the cut-off time when the check-in is deemed late?

Based on some recommended times that I recently saw on Air Canada, hold baggage drop-off/check-in time could be earlier than a check-in time with all carry-on luggage. I don't have a specific case though.

@mkennedy see the link in my answer, that's not unusual.

"Late" means "coming or remaining after the due, usual, or proper time". "Late check-in" means check-in after the check-in deadline. Usually, airlines would tell you in the reservation confirmation or on their website when is the last time to check in for a flight. For international flights this is usually (from my experience) somewhere close to 1 hour before departure. The deadlines depend on regulatory requirements, time to process the manifest and luggage, and the complexities of the airports (I've seen the same airline having different check-in limits in different airports for the same types of travel).
If you arrive to the check-in counter after the check-in deadline for the flight, the airline may at its discretion still allow you through, but you might need to sign this limited release of liability for the various cases of mishaps that may occur as the result of you being late.

I've been a "late check-in" after losing a wallet and wasting some time trying to find it in the Hbf in the past. I was told that I should come earlier in the future when checking in, that it's normally closed but that they'll give me an exception. By the time I was at border queue I was on last call, eventually I made it to the flight, and on the other end my luggage wasn't delayed. Alas: I was not required to sign any such thing. This was an intl flight out of Leipzig-Halle Airport operated by Turkish Airlines. This is up to the airline at best.

@ave hbf=Hauptbahnhof?

@FranckDernoncourt yep. (My wallet was never found btw :/)

@ave notice how I say "might" or "depends" or "may at its discretion". Without knowing the specifics we cannot say for certain what will happen, what conditions are altered, etc. Different airlines may behave differently in the same situation, maybe even the same airline will behave differently to different customers (e.g.: will accept late checkins from a high-level frequent traveler in first class while declining a random basic fare traveler).

@littleadv of course, I just wanted to offer a personal experience as someone who's been a "late check-in", it wasn't supposed to go against your post, only add to it.
